# Pycharm type error: Expected type literal got list["Model"]

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-typing, sqlmodel

I write fastapi sqlmodel sqlalchemy project. I got type error in PyCharm:

```
expected type 'Literal["*"] | QueryableAttribute', got 'list[Account] | None' instead
```

error was caused by this code:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import selectinload


class CRUDCounterPartyCommon(
    CRUDBase[CounterParty, CounterpartyCommonCreateUpdateSchema, CounterpartyCommonCreateUpdateSchema]
):
    async def get_by_uuid(self, db: AsyncSession, *, _uuid: uuid.UUID) -> Optional[CounterParty]:
        counterparty = select(CounterParty).where(CounterParty.id == _uuid).options(selectinload(CounterParty.accounts))
```

Warning was caused by selectinload. What should I do to solve this problem?

**Update**

mypy says:

```
error: Argument 1 to "selectinload" has incompatible type "list[Account] | None"; expected "Literal['*'] | QueryableAttribute[Any]"  [arg-type]
```

Base CRUD class that is ok according to PyCharm linter when we are talking about selectinload:

```
class CRUDBase(Generic[ModelType, CreateSchemaType, UpdateSchemaType]):
    async def get_by_field_name(
        self,
        db: AsyncSession,
        field_name: str,
        field_value: str,
        _select: ModelType,
        selection_load_options: Optional[List[Tuple]] = None,
        conditions: Optional[List[Tuple]] = None,
        joins: Optional[List[Tuple]] = None,
    ) -> ModelType:
        query = select(_select)
        if joins:
            for table, condition in joins:
                query = query.join(table, condition)
        if selection_load_options:
            for options_tuple in selection_load_options:
                options_obj = None
                for option in options_tuple:
                    if options_obj is None:
                        options_obj = selectinload(option)
                    else:
                        options_obj = options_obj.options(selectinload(option))
                if options_obj:
                    query = query.options(options_obj)
        if conditions:
            for key, value, comparison in conditions:
                query = query.where(comparison(key, value))
        query = query.where(field_name == field_value)
        try:
            query = query.group_by(self.model.id)
        except Exception:
            pass
```

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with pycharm or is that just the IDE you happen to be using?

Comment: Please show us [mypy *.py](https://pypi.org/project/mypy) output, or whatever type checking linter your IDE ran to produce that diagnostic. Also, how does removing `*,` from the function signature affect things?

Comment: @possum I mean that I use default PyCharm linter

Comment: @J_H I do not use mypy. I use default linter in PyCharm. Removing * does not affect on linter.

Comment: Please pip install the linked mypy linter, and share its output.

Comment: @J_H thank you for your attention. I added mypy error in the post

Answer (score 0):

There is more to this puzzle which you choose not to tell us about.

```
        ... select(CounterParty)... options(selectinload(CounterParty.accounts))
```

It seems perfectly reasonable to me that `accounts`
would be an optional `list[Account]` type.
Consider imposing a non-NULL constraint,
so it must at least be the empty list.

It's unclear where the `Literal["*"] | QueryableAttribute`
type came from, but an
[MRO](https://web.archive.org/web/20240102013331/https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro)
that mentions CounterpartyCommonCreateUpdateSchema
seems a likely candidate.
At least for debugging,
try removing it to see if that changes what `mypy` says.
Also, I can't imagine why you chose to list it twice.
The second occurrence produces no useful effect.

There's more than one way to accomplish the aim of this call:

```
    ... .options(selectinload(CounterParty.accounts))
```

Somewhere you define a `relationship()`.
We could tack on a `, lazy="selectin"`
[parameter](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/loading_relationships.html#relationship-loading-techniques)
there, for the same effect.
Then `mypy` would have less visibility into what's happening
and less reason to complain.

You might also choose to use
[.awaitable_attrs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/asyncio.html#asyncio-orm-avoid-lazyloads).

Comment: Literal comes from sqlalchemy selectinload method
def selectinload(
    *keys: _AttrType, recursion_depth: Optional[int] = None
) -> _AbstractLoad:
_AttrType = Union[Literal["*"], "QueryableAttribute[Any]"]

Comment: CounterpartyCommonCreateUpdateSchema is used because base class CRUDBase has options Model, CreateSchema, UpdateSchema. I did not write it. I just inherired specific class from base class

Comment: Sooo, now all we have to do is come up with a `QueryableAttribute`, right? Somehow `.accounts` doesn't fit, though it seems like it should. If your codebase has other examples of attributes, some of them queryable, then we could play the "what detail is different?" game.

Comment: I added base class in description. I should use this method but it is still interesting why do I get warning from PyCharm

Comment: if we add `lazy="selectin"` at model's relationship level, every future query on the model will use the lazy automatically which might be unnecessary each time. I think that's why @Konstantinos put it dynamically at query level when he needs the relationship get returned on the fly. FastAPI with SQLModel itself hasn't provide a detailed async example for this part, I also use very similar code as he does, it works, but MyPy is not happy. Although SQLModel is designed to solve the SqlAlchemy typing issue, we still have some. For e.g. the `in_` parameter in `where` clause.